# Rendering async component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 state full components App.js and LoadBoard.jsx. I want to fetch data in LoadBoard and display it in App.js. The problem is that LoadBoard.jsx is displaying data before fetching it. In this application I'am going to fetch data about 6 times so I prefer if I could do it in different components, instead of App.js

My thoughts

1. Obviously In App.js I could put if statement in render, To render values only after fetching. Problem is that I don't have access to positionToId in App.js. Should I store positionToId in App.js instead of LoadBoard.jsx?

   `if(this.state.positionToID.length > 0){
    <LoadBoard
   apiBase = {this.state.apiBase}/>
   }`

**APP.JS**

```
render(){

}
return(
<div className="col-xs-10">
                <div id="game_board" className="row">
                <LoadBoard 
                apiBase = {this.state.apiBase}
                />
)
```

**LoadBoard.jsx**

```
class LoadBoard extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       positionToId: [],

     }
   }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({loading: true});
      Axios.get(this.props.apiBase + 'configuration')
        .then(response => {
          let idArray = [];
          for (let index = 0; index < response.data.slots; index++) {              
            idArray.push(response.data.positionToId[index]);
            this.setState({loading: false});
          }

        this.setState({positionToId: idArray})
        console.log(this.state.positionToId);
        })

        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
   }
  render() {
    let LoadBoard = <h1>This is displayed</h1>;
    if(this.state.positionToId.length> 0){
        return <h1>This is not displayed</h1>
    }
    return (
      <div>
      {LoadBoard}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `this.state.positionToId.length > 0`?
Since `positionToId` is an array, it won't have a `value`, and `undefined > 0` will always be `false`

Comment: This could already solve your problem, because it should render the "This is not displayed" headline as long as no results have been received

Comment: Yes it fixed it, thanks.